# Server side dates formatting

Tags: node.js, date, server, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a nodejs server that I am sending messages from him.
I want to format dates by the receiver localization data. If he is from US so the hour will be 2:00 pm and if he is from UK the hour will be 14:00.
I have the user timezone.

Answer (score 0):

try using moment-timezone

```js
import momentTimezone from "https://esm.sh/moment-timezone";
console.log(momentTimezone().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format())
console.log(momentTimezone().tz("Europe/London").format())
```